# jQuery or any javascript for obligatory attribution link

Tags: javascript, jquery

the idea is to :

- have a script which embed an attribution link to the website,
- then this script should be integrated into the main script which makes the website working,
- then this global script should be encryted that visitors can not read it...

or

- have just an embed attribution link like this :

I use a Blogger template for one of my blog (http://prohungarica.blogspot.com) where the template author has integrated to its attribution (you can see the belowest and i can not find how he did... i would like the same thing to my own templates.

How might I do this?

I am interested in other than jQuery or javascript too !

EDIT :

So the first part of my question will be too difficult for my knowledge and some people did not even understand, the second part of my question remains :

How to embed an attribution link in my own template that users can not take it off, just like the example in my blog (see here above) ? Maybe with a jQuery or other javascript ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "this global script should be encrypted that visitors can not read it"? If your script is encrypted, you'll have to add a JavaScript decryption function, too. The client needs to read your code.

Comment: @Juhana : is that you who gave me a down vote ? Only for you, if you did not read my question above : My question is HOW TO SHOW AN ATTRIBUTION LINK WHAT NOBODY CAN TAKE OFF ! Hope it helps !

Comment: @mts7 : a script for the demo page, of course. I did not say CLIENT, you said that, i said VISITORS !

Comment: @guest (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1864688/guest) i do not understand anything about Stackoverflow system and functions, i guess this is because of my English and also because i am coming here only to get what i would like but not to learn another community website.. so, i do not know how to edited my question but at least you wanted to help me with your suggested question, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> HOW TO SHOW AN ATTRIBUTION LINK WHAT NOBODY CAN TAKE OFF

[The web is not a good place to achieve such a thing.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-design-principles/#priority-of-constituencies) An explicit design goal of HTML is to make life easier for the user (visitor), even if doing so makes life harder for the author.

> have a script which embed an attribution link to the website

(That's the easy part, which you already know how to do.)

> then this script should be integrated into the main script which makes the website working

This tends to be hard, because the web browser is usually what makes most of a website "working." Anything you write as an author rather than an *implementor* is well isolated from the browser. I think the most you could do here is come up with a new layer of abstraction between the browser and the content. Otherwise it would be too easy to isolate the attribution logic. This is no small endeavor.

> then this global script should be encryted that visitors can not read it

You probably mean "obfuscated." Encryption would prevent the visitor's browser from running the script, unless you also handed over the keys, which would make it pointless. Obfuscation keeps the code runnable, but makes it harder (though not impossible) for humans to understand. That said, it's inappropriate to give product recommendations on Stackoverflow, but I hope this clarification helps you find what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it did not help me :( Ok, the first part of my question is difficult for my knowledge and maybe i did not explain it well with my English. but i really would like to know how the author of the template of my blog did show his attribution that i can not find even with Firebug, it would be perfect for my own templates. When you work hard and spent a lot of time, even if you can not sale a template but you need at least that the users let your attribution in it !
So, the question is : how to embed an attribution link that template users can not find it to delete...